# React Context not being updated

Tags: reactjs, react-context

When I create a user then try to fetch the user on another page it still shows the default user.

When I console.log this on any route it shows the user as null still even thought I just created it

```
  const { user, setUser } = React.useContext(UserContext);
```

Provider

```
function App() {
  const [user, setUser] = React.useState({
    name: null,
    password: null,
    balance: 0,
    email: null,
  });

  return (
    <UserContext.Provider value={{ user, setUser }}>
      <Router>
        <div>
          <Navbar />
          <div style={{ display: "flex", justifyContent: "center" }}>
            <Routes>
              <Route exact path="/" element={<Home />} />
              <Route exact path="/create-account" element={<CreateAccount />} />
              <Route exact path="/deposit" element={<Deposit />} />
              <Route exact path="/withdraw" element={<Withdraw />} />
              <Route exact path="/alldata" element={<AllData />} />
            </Routes>
          </div>
        </div>
      </Router>
    </UserContext.Provider>
  );
}
```

Setting the context

```
function CreateAccount() {
  const [form, setForm] = React.useState({});
  const [errors, setErrors] = React.useState(null);
  const { setUser } = React.useContext(UserContext);

  const setField = (field, value) => {
    setForm({
      ...form,
      [field]: value,
    });

    if (!!errors) {
      setErrors({
        ...errors,
        [field]: null,
      });
    }
  };

  const validateForm = () => {
    const { name, password, email } = form;
    const newErrors = {};

    if (!name) {
      newErrors.name = "Name is required";
    }

    if (!password) {
      newErrors.password = "Password is required";
    }

    if (!email) {
      newErrors.email = "Email is required";
    }

    return newErrors;
  };

  const handleSubmit = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();

    const formErrors = validateForm();

    if (Object.keys(formErrors).length > 0) {
      setErrors(formErrors);
    } else {
      alert("User created successfully");
      const newUser = {
        name: form.name,
        password: form.password,
        email: form.email,
        balance: 0,
      };
      setUser(newUser);
    }
  };

  const handleClear = () => {
    setForm({});
    setErrors(null);
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <div>Create account</div>
      <form>
        <div className="form-group">
          <label htmlFor="inputName">Name</label>
          <input
            type="text"
            className="form-control"
            id="inputName"
            placeholder="Enter name"
            onChange={(e) => setField("name", e.target.value)}
            value={form.name || ""}
          />
          {errors && errors.name && (
            <small id="nameHelp" className="form-text text-danger">
              {errors.name}
            </small>
          )}
        </div>
        <div className="form-group">
          <label htmlFor="InputEmail">Email address</label>
          <input
            type="email"
            className="form-control"
            id="InputEmail"
            aria-describedby="emailHelp"
            placeholder="Enter email"
            onChange={(e) => setField("email", e.target.value)}
            value={form.email || ""}
          />
          {errors && errors.email && (
            <small id="emailHelp" className="form-text text-danger">
              {errors.email}
            </small>
          )}
        </div>
        <div className="form-group">
          <label htmlFor="InputPassword">Password</label>
          <input
            type="password"
            className="form-control"
            id="InputPassword"
            placeholder="Password"
            required
            onChange={(e) => setField("password", e.target.value)}
            value={form.password || ""}
          />
          {errors && errors.password && (
            <small id="passwordHelp" className="form-text text-danger">
              {errors.password}
            </small>
          )}
        </div>
        <button
          type="reset"
          className="btn btn-secondary"
          onClick={handleClear}
        >
          Clear
        </button>
        <button
          type="submit"
          className="btn btn-primary"
          onClick={handleSubmit}
        >
          Create account
        </button>
      </form>
    </div>
  );
}
```

My goal is to get the user on the other context so that I can manage the fake account

Comment: where is the code for creating context 

Comment: @KcH do you mean the file where the context is created so its this line inside a file `export const UserContext = createContext(null); `

Comment: I made a sample [example of almost same e.g.](https://codesandbox.io/s/crazy-shape-r5nh87?file=/src/App.js) .... not sure what is wrong in your code (if possible you can make a sample as similar and share)

Comment: I used the dev tools and I noticed that the context is reset when I use a navbar to change to another component

Comment: The issue was that the navbar was using a and not Link components so it refreshed and lost the information